# How to prevent R Expss from mixing variable name with row label in output data frame?

Tags: r, expss

When running table using Expss package, the variable label gets mixed with each row in the dataframe (tables are output as dataframes). See code below. You will notice that each row label gets prepended with the variable label "Gender" and a bar | character. How to prevent this?

```
#Required packages
library(magrittr)
require("ggplot2") 
library(expss)

#Create dataframe
gen<-c("Male","Male","Female","Female")
data<-data.frame(gen)
names(data)<-"Q1"

#Apply var label
data = apply_labels(data,
Q1 = "Gender")

#Tabulate
tarb<-data %>%
tab_cells(Q1) %>%
tab_stat_cpct() %>%
tab_pivot()

#View table
tarb

#Check what is in the row_labels column - notice gender | prepended 

tarb$row_labels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. If you need variable label in the separate column you can use `split_columns` function:

```
library(expss)

#Create dataframe
gen<-c("Male","Male","Female","Female")
data<-data.frame(gen)
names(data)<-"Q1"

#Apply var label
data = apply_labels(data,
                    Q1 = "Gender")

#Tabulate
tarb<-data %>%
    tab_cells(Q1) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_pivot()


tarb = split_columns(tarb)
tarb
#                        #Total
# 1 Gender       Female     50
# 2                Male     50
# 3        #Total cases      4
```

Comment: Unfortunately the command 'split_columns(tarb)' doesn't seem to change it. Please check using tarb$row_labels or using a viewer such as R Commander data editor.

Comment: @CK7 `tarb = split_columns(tarb); str(tarb)` - works for me. There is no `row_labels` column after the split.

Comment: please paste in answer box, as Stackoverflow does not allow me to mark your response as answered/solved if it is in the form of comment.

Comment: @GregoryDemin This solution won't help with a table like this:   `htmlTable(mpg %>% tab_rows(model %nest% class, total()) %>% tab_cols(fl)%>%tab_stat_sum()%>%tab_pivot())`  How to remove the text "cell var" and "Sum" ?

Comment: @Ben You need to add label to `tab_sum` and specify cell variables for sum with `tab_cells`: `htmlTable(mpg %>% tab_rows(model %nest% class, total()) %>% tab_cells(???) %>% tab_cols(fl)%>%tab_stat_sum(label = "")%>%tab_pivot())`